# Плавное увеличение/уменьшение числа

Tags: c#, математика

Нужна помощь математиков, ибо я, как говорится, не бум-бум

Покадрово рисую гифку на 180 кадров, в гифке колесо, которое по задумке изначально крутится быстро, и по итогу плавно останавливается, но я не понимаю, как сделать плавное замедление

Накидал минимальный-упрощённый пример того, как это происходит сейчас. Делаю какое-то подобие ускорения вращения, а по завершению цикла беру выходные картинки из папки и переворачиваю список, но остановка сейчас слишком резкая

```
int totalFrames = 180;
float lastAngle = 0;

for (int frame = 0; frame < totalFrames; frame++) {
    Image img = Image.FromFile(...);
    Image main = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

    float angle = 0;
    if (frame > 15)
        angle = (lastAngle + frame / 5f) % 360; << вот тут нужна плавность

    lastAngle = angle;

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(main)) {
        g.DrawImage(RotateImage(img, angle), new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
        main.Save($"out/{frame}.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это Winforms?..

Comment: @aepot не думаю, что это имеет хоть какое-то значение. Используется system.drawing

Comment: Все зависит от того, сколько кадров в секунду в `gif`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko кмк, нет здесь никакого gif, а просто самопальная анимация статичной картинки. С сохранением каждого кадра в отдельный жпег (зачем?). Но автор не раскрывает подробности логики рендера на экран, так как считает, что весь смысл анимации в формуле расчета угла, а не задержке между кадрами, с помощью которой кстати и должен высчитываться угол поворота из заданной [угловой скорости](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity) для каждого кадра. Налицо проблема XY.

Comment: @aepot тогда просветите меня, глупца, в то, как правильно создавать гифку

Comment: Вы разве создаете где-то gif файл? Или просто рисуете на экран? Покажите ваш код, который создает гифку. Прикрепите саму гифку, где визуально понятно, в чем именно проблема, или вы хотите чтобы я или кто-то другой весь код рендера написал с нуля?

Comment: @aepot суть вопроса написана в вопросе, и в нём я не просил Вас писать код рендера. Прикрепил код создания гиф

Comment: @aepot как я понял, автор с помощью средств c# хочет сгенерировать последовательные картинки, которые можно скормить какой-то сторонней программе и вернуть `gif` - файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плавное торможение достигается за счет **уменьшения скорости вращения колеса** (или угловой скорости). Скорость вращения колеса (в формулах и коде буду применять обозначение `vAngular`) - это угол, на который поворачивается колесо за единицу времени. В вашем случае - это поворот на ***x*** градусов за 1 кадр.

Эту скорость `vAngular` необходимо плавно уменьшать со значения `vAngularStart` до значения `vAngularEnd = 0` за определенный промежуток времени. Чтобы уменьшать скорость в цикле - необходимо найти некоторую `vDelta` - изменение скорости вращения за 1 кадр. Она вычисляется по формуле:

```
vDelta = (vAgularEnd - vAngularStart) / deltaT
```

где `deltaT` - **время торможения.**

Поскольку скорость в вашем случае уменьшается, то `vDelta` будет отрицательная.

Применяя все выше сказанное к вашему коду, получаем следующее:

```
int totalFrames = 180;
int frameStartBraking = 15; // Фрейм, с которого начинаем торможение
float deltaT = totalFrames - frameStartBraking;

float vAngularStart = 30; // Скорость вращения колеса при начале торможения.
float vAngularCurrent = vAngularStart; // Считаем, что до торможения скорость колеса вращения не изменялась
float vAgularEnd = 0; // Конечная скорость вращения колеса
float vDelta = (vAgularEnd - vAngularStart) / (totalFrames - frameStartBraking);

float angle = 0;
for (int frame = 0; frame < totalFrames; frame++) {

    //...
    
    if (frame > frameStartBraking) {
        vAngularCurrent += deltaV;
    }
    
    angle += vAngularCurrent;

    //...
}
```

Регулируется плавность торможения за счет изменения величин `vAngularStart` и `deltaT`.

Единственный нюанс: этот расчет не гарантирует того, что в последнем фрейме ваше колесо будет повернуто на `angle = 0`.

Comment: Стоит заметить, здесь представлено линейное изменение угловой скорости. Автор возможно хочет "плавное", что-то типа ease, можно ввернуть какой-ниудь фрагмент синуса или квадратичную функцию или S-образную, если речь про полный интервал времени пойдет, а не про половину. Но идея правильная.

Comment: @aepot да, линейное, все верно. Можно сделать в момент старта и окончания торможения плавно возрастающие/затухающие кривые, но тут уже в теории я не силен. Я понимаю, что нужно vDelta в таком случае менять в цикле, но вот чтобы построить красивую функцию - у меня не хватит знаний

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zjP342h4 это проще чем кажется, вот перемещатор мышки, красиво ее разгоняющий и красиво тормозящий. Смысл идеи в том, что начало анимации 0%, а конец - 100%. Берешь функцию, которая вернет значение от 0 до 1, пока ты ее кормишь своими процентами, и готово. Например косинус, как по ссылке. Выглядит оно гораздо круче, чем линейное. Главный смысл в том, что функция от 0 вернет 0 и от 1 вернет 1, а в промежутке там любая хитровывитая кривая может быть. Так собственно и работает easing в нормальных анимациях.